# Numpy use dispatcher for argument displacement

Tags: numpy

This question is specific to [NEP 18](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html), which proposes a dispatch mechanism for using an arbitrary functions together with classes that implement the `__array_function__` interface (such as `np.ndarray`).

```
def _einsum_dispatcher(subscripts, *operands):
    return (*operands,), dict(subscripts=subscripts)

@np.core.overrides.array_function_dispatch(_einsum_dispatcher, verify=False)
def my_einsum(*operands, **subscripts):
    raise RuntimeError("This should currently never happen")

class ArrayLike:
    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        return f"""
               func = {func},
               types = {types},
               args = {args},
               kwargs = {kwargs}
               """
```

Running a test for `my_einsum` we get

```
a = ArrayLike()
print(my_einsum('...', a))
```

Output:

```
RuntimeError: This should currently never happen
```

The function never gets intercepted by `__array_function__` method for `ArrayLike`. Although, this can be solved by changing the dispatcher a  bit:

```
def _einsum_dispatcher(subscripts, *operands):
    return (*operands,)
```

Now when testing `my_einsum` the exact same way again:

```
a = ArrayLike()
print(my_einsum('...', a))
```

Output:

```
func = <function my_einsum at 0x7efded61bd30>,
types = (<class '__main__.ArrayLike'>,),
args = ('...', <__main__.ArrayLike object at 0x7efdef83efa0>),
kwargs = {}
```

The function is correct, but how do I move the `subscripts` argument into `kwargs` ? Can the [`array_function_dispatch`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e104f03ac8f65ae5b92a9b413b0fa639f39e6de2/numpy/core/overrides.py#L64) only be used to dispatch argument types?

Comment: While the docs say: `einsum(subscripts, *operands, ...`, the actual code is `def einsum(*operands, ...`.  That is, `subscripts` is just the first of the `operands` - if it is a string.  There's an alternative syntax that intersperces operands and sublists.  There's a comment about this in `_einsum_path_dispatcher` and `_einsum_dispatcher`.

Comment: My problem is not really specific to the einsum dispatcher. But it looks it is not possible for the dispatcher to rearrange the arguments at all: "*Dispatcher functions are required to share the exact same positional, optional and keyword-only arguments as their corresponding NumPy functions.*". i'm just confused about the use of dispatchers, is it just for type inference?